# Why is the concatenated string at the end totally different from what the code does?

Tags: c, pdflatex

The code below might seem big, but it's really simple. I wanted to make an exercise generator in C, which concatenates latex formatted strings, stored in the function local arrays.

But the output is totally not what I expected it to be. I might have done something wrong with the pointers, or some overflow somewhere.

Tried all the tips I could find on internet:

(1) Initialize a string with '\0' at position 0;
(2) Use a pointer to the string to pass to the function;

```c
int create_exercise_string(char **s, int s_size) {
    // The format of the exercise is x+n=m;
    // ASCII 48-57 = '0' ... '9';
    int exercises_left = 10;
    char *exercise;
    char operation_list[][2] = {"+\0", "-\0"};
    char equal[] = "&=&"; // & is for centering on the item contained in latex;
    char array_begin[] = "\\begin{eqnarray*}\n";
    char array_end[] = "\\end{eqnarray*}";
    char number[1];

    strcat(*s, array_begin);
    s_size -= strlen(array_begin);

    //REMOVE
    puts("before exercise generation");
    while (exercises_left > 0 && s_size > 0) {
        exercise = malloc(256);
        if (!exercise) {
            puts("allocating error, quitting...");
            getchar();
            exit(1);
        }

        exercise[0] = '\0';
// THE INTERESTED PART =================================================
        if (exercises_left < 10)
            strcat(exercise, "\\\\\n");
        printf("exercise number %d\n", exercises_left);
        strcpy(exercise, "x");
        //add an operator
        strcat(exercise, operation_list[rand() % 2]);
        // add a number
        number[0] = (rand() % 10) + 48;
        strcat(exercise, number);
        // add an equal
        strcat(exercise, equal);
        // add a number
        number[0] = (rand() % 10) + 48;
        strcat(exercise, number);
// END =================================================================
        s_size -= strlen(exercise);
        strcat(*s, exercise);
        free(exercise);
        exercises_left--;
    }
    //REMOVE
    puts("exercise generation ended");

    if (s_size < strlen(array_end)) {
        puts("create_exercise_string: buffer overflow detected, quitting...");
        getchar();
        exit(1); // for now... will be substituted with proper code
    }
    else strcat(*s, array_end);

    puts("allocation worked, returning in main");
    return exercises_left; // 0 if succesfull;
}
```

I was expecting the output to be like this

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
x-9&=&3\\
x+3&=&12\\
x-2&=&3\\
... 7 other exercises
\end{eqnarray*}
```

But I actually get

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
x-5\end{eqnarray*}&=&9\end{eqnarray*}x-9\end{eqnarray*}&=&2\end{eqnarray*}x+3\end{eqnarray*}&=&1\end{eqnarray*}x-7\end{eqnarray*}&=&0\end{eqnarray*}x+6\end{eqnarray*}&=&1\end{eqnarray*}x-6\end{eqnarray*}&=&5\end{eqnarray*}x+6\end{eqnarray*}&=&8\end{eqnarray*}x-8\end{eqnarray*}&=&6\end{eqnarray*}x+4\end{eqnarray*}&=&5\end{eqnarray*}x+1\end{eqnarray*}&=&5\end{eqnarray*}\end{eqnarray*}
```

With no \n added overall, and some \end{eqnarray*} repeatedly added...

What is wrong?

Comment: For one `char number[1]` should be `char number[2]` -- you always need a byte for the null-string terminator.

Comment: `exercise[0] = '\0'` I think this is also problematic, since whatever you'll *concatenate* to the end of the string will be ignored because the null character will be encountered before.

Comment: @GasperStukelj it should replace the '\0' with the initial character of the appending string... there is a '\0' missing somewhere, and I am trying to figure it out. strcat() should always append a terminating null to a string, the problem should be in the way I have declared some strings... maybe referring to one of them doesn't have a terminating null, and this string is right before \end{enqarray*}, so it gets wrote again, and the end of this there is surely a '\0'... now I also need to understand why \\\\\n is not appended. I have to say my coding is a bit of a mess!

Comment: ... you also need to nul-terminate the corrected `char number[2]` after writing the digit to `number[0]`. You can't use `strcat()` without that terminator on all strings, and it is not present by default.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

All I can say is, when working with strings, always keep in mind if the terminating character is added or not, so in my case, I need to reinforce the study of strings allocation in C.

The problem was the variable number[1].

```
number[0] = rand() % 10 + 48;
```

This code adds the char representation of a number between 0 and 9 [48,57] in ASCII.

But it doesn't add a terminating null character!

Everytime I concatenated `number` to the `exercise` string, it overflowed to another local variable which had the terminating null character, thus the "undefined behaviour" of `strcat()` was that it kept reading another local variable.

Lucky me in memory there was a '\0' minefield, otherwise I would have needed to bang my head on the wall, if protected memory was tried to be read.

Thanks for the help!